# IoT Edge - C2D and File Upload

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Has anyone come up with a clever work-around for the limit of IoT Edge device modules not supporting cloud-to-device messaging or file-uploading?

(ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-development)

> Currently, a module cannot receive cloud-to-device messages nor use
>   the file upload feature.

Is it going to be available come GA (General Availability), or do we need to come up with ad-hoc solutions going forward?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with C2D messages? Would Direct Methods work for you instead? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods) The big difference is that they aren't queued like C2D messages...if you invoke a direct method in the cloud and the target module isn't connected, you'll get an immediate error response.

Comment: I can't really think of any real reason, besides the message delivery "guarantee" - but if I wanted to tell a module "hey, operate differently" - I could stamp that in the module twin instead as a state change.

Comment: I have posted an how to on triggering direct methods from a backend app here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145260/how-can-computation-on-an-iotedge-module-be-triggered-from-within-a-net-core-ap

Answer (score 0):

This is just registered in GitHub to know if file upload is possible from IoT Edge module => [Upload file from IoT Edge Module #603](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/issues/603)

Answer (score 0):

For the file upload, you can potentially use the Edge blob storage module

[documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-store-data-blob)

it's not quite the same experience as the file upload from the SDK, but it is consistent with the azure blob APIs, and may be even be more robust.